# SharePoint rest api to get Group members full details

Tags: rest, sharepoint-online

I am getting `SharePoint` group members details by calling endpoint

```
/_api/web/site groups/getbyname('Group Name')/users
```

However, I am only getting limited user properties. I would like to retrieve other properties like `First Name`, `Last Name` and other `AD` attributes.

What would be the way out for it?
Thank you for your help.

Regards,
PRS

Answer (score 1):

you called a SharePoint REST api. It's supposed to return sharepoint data which only related to the site. However, you need more details. Those user information should be recorded in Azure AD. I don't think sharepoint rest api is able to response you any information from Azure AD.

Well, Microsoft Graph is possible to return more details of users, please check this link:
https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/v1.0/resources/users

The only thing you need is user ID!

Sharepoint rest api's response includes User's Displayname! What if you replace each user's displayname with User ID from system admin center, then your app could use the displacename (acturally is User ID) to call Microsoft Graph to retrieve user's information from Azure AD.

Let's try it.